# Why do some turboprop engines require motoring after shut down?

Tags: aircraft-design

A retired pilot I know told me about his time flying a Cessna 441 Conquest II. He said that after shut down he'd have to go out and motor the props. What engines require this procedure and what is the purpose?

Comment: I can think of a number of things one might do to an engine/propeller combination after shut down, but I've never heard any of them described as 'motoring'. Can you clarify what you mean here?

Comment: I've always heard it referred to as "motoring" conversationally. Maybe we'll get an answer that references the term.

Comment: @Airsick I found a [manual from a Cessna 208B](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ryanburnette-cfi/Grand-Caravan-Pilot-Information-Manual.pdf) that uses the word "motoring" several times.

Comment: Thank you. Since it was an unfamiliar term I did a number of searches but turned up nothing. I've learned something today!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rotating the propeller of the Cessna 441 Conquest II is to cool the [Garrett TPE331](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garrett_TPE331) engine in the aircraft. From [airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/tech_ops/read.main/14639)

> On the Garrett TPE331's we were trained to spin the props after shutdown to get cooling air flowing through the engine, this was done right after shutdown. Half an hour after we did the prop spins we had go back out to the aircraft and rotate the propellers one blade width. Moving the prop one blade width rotated the engine one half turn, this was to prevent the shaft from sagging as the engine cooled causing turbine blades to rub.

The reason is given as:

> Direct drive turbo prop engines sometimes require this to remove residual heat from the engine because once the prop stops turning, so does the engine. When the pilot turns the prop, depending on the gear ratio, he is actually spinning the engine very fast. This helps move some of the heat out of the engine.

Comment: Wait... `direct drive` ... `gear ratio` ... what?

Comment: @egid https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garrett_TPE331#/media/File:Turboprop_cutaway.jpg

Comment: Its got an integral gearbox. How is it "direct drive"? :) I don't follow.

Comment: @egid, apparently it is direct drive because it has just one turbine (3-stage, but common shaft) that drives both the propeller and the compressor. In contrast most other turboprops have separate HP turbine driving compressor and LP turbine driving the propeller.

Answer (score 8):

The TPE331 in all of its flavors is susceptible to "shaft bow," a condition in which the shaft connecting the compressors and turbines actually bends enough to seize the engine.  Even a tiny amount of bow will seize an engine.  Pilots of planes with the TPE331 (like the Conquest II, Merlins/Metroliner, MU2, etc) are trained to spin the engine through to remove residual heat from the engine core.  Spinning the prop through a few rotation causes the compressor/turbine sections to spin, expelling the heat (...or so pilots are taught!).  With a gear ratio of approximately 23:1, spinning the propeller all the way through once spins the core 23 times.

The primary concern is **not** heat removal.  No amount of manual spinning will "cool" the engine after it has just shut down!  It's really, *really* hot inside of a freshly run engine and to think a few rotations of a propeller can exhaust that heat is silly.  Also, as the moment the engine is shut off, it spins freely for hundreds of rotations until it comes to a stop.  That free spinning as the engine winds down is sucking in more cool air than a pilot could possibly move through the engine manually!  The reason pilots are told to spin the prop (whether they know it or not) is to simply reorient the shaft so that it doesn't start to sag.  In reality, after all of that free spinning at shutdown, the propeller only needs to be moved a few blade widths to prevent shaft bow.  At a 23:1 gear ratio, rotating the prop a mere 7.8 degrees reorients the turbine shaft 180 degrees. That measly 7.8 degrees is what *really* prevents shaft bow!  Operators of TPE331 equipped plane train their pilots to spin props many times just to make sure that the pilots actually move the prop enough to reorient the shaft.  Adjusting the prop 7.8 degrees or spinning it through 1000 times won't hurt the engine...only **not** rotating the shaft will cause damage...over time...maybe...if you're really unlucky.

Realistically, a pilot exiting a TPE331 equipped aircraft need only give the prop a playful nudge in the normal direction of rotation to prevent shaft bow.  Spinning though X-number of times won't hurt anything, but it's not necessary either.  Also, no need to go out 30 minutes later for another spin session.  These engines aren't made of glass...they just require a moment of attention after they've been run.

A certain company I worked for wanted me to spin the prop through 30 blades after each shutdown.  That procedure did not change between the 3 and 4 blade props...so, exactly *why* were 30 blades chosen? Never got an answer to that!

The TPE331 is a wonderful engine.